# Send order information to paypal express check-out?

Tags: paypal

Ive come across an implementation of PayPal's Check-Out service - I assume it is Express Checkout - where once I am sent to PayPal, the personal details and ordrered products are already listed and filled out, and only waiting for me to fill in my credit card information as a guest.

I havent been able to find instruction for this anywhere in PayPal's API.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following example

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<table width=750px>
<tr>
<td align=right valign=middle width=550px>
<font size=2 face=arial><b>To Purchase "Test Item Name" - $100.00Click Here ---></b></font>
</td>
<td width=200px valign=middle align=left>
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youPaypalid@domain.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Test120">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100.00">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">     
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

You can check detailed information about it on the following URL

[Paypal developers documentation](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted)

Comment: That will let the customer change order information, so that will not work.

Comment: This is also referring to Payments Standard, not Express Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal provides lots of [documentation for Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec).  I would recommend specifically looking at the [Express Checkout Integration Guide](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide.pdf) and the [NVP](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf) or [SOAP](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_api_reference.pdf) documentation depending on which you're more comfortable with.

To get the desired effect you've specified (Guest checkout always being available) you need to pass SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing in your [SetExpressCheckout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/setexpresscheckout-api-operation-nvp) request.